# Java Html Table to Plain text

Tags: java, html, html-table

We save incomming emails in database.
We then save one version with all the html-tags removed.
The problem with this is that if the mail includes a table like this:

Heading1 Heading2

column1 column2

it looks like this after removing tags

Heading1

Heading2

column1

column2

Is there a simple way to get a html table and turn it to plain text but with the formating still intact. At least with linebreaks in the right places

So the table turns into something like:
Heading1 Heading2 \r\n column1 column2 \r\n.
Or something similar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

Comment: It looks like you are adding the linebreaks after each cell (that is after each `</th>` and `</td>`) and that you should instead add them after each row (that is after each `</tr>`). But this is too obvious so it probably just means that you should add some more info to your question, f.ex. a sample of the HTML you are dealing with.

Comment: Yes maybe I should have added more info.
The way I currently save it is with:
(String)part.getContent();
Where part is of type javax.mail.Part.
So I dont do any linebreaks myself.
This gives a result like 
\r\n To: emailaddress \r\n Subject: ...
Which has worked fine. It is only when the mail includes a table that I would like it to not make linebreaks between the <td>
It would be nice if I could continue using the current solution with the javax.mail.part and just add something to handle the tables somehow.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way?  Not really.  HTML tables are complex, and can have row spans and column spans, not to mention normal HTML attributes like bidirectional text.  CSS attributes like `display: table-cell;` can also cause otherwise ordinary HTML to suddenly become a table.

However, if you don't really care too much about formatting and just want to output multiple columns onto the same line, you could parse the HTML using something like JTidy or Jericho, then output multiple `<td>` or `<th>` tags by putting spaces between them, and when you get the end of a `<tr>` element, you could output `"\r\n"`.

If you really don't want to parse the HTML, you could just replace `<td>` and `<th>` tags themselves with a single space or tab, and `<tr>` with a linebreak.  This may get you at least some reasonable results.